# Parent state resolve before validating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a couple of states set up in my angular application that look like this:

```
.state('createOrder', {
    url: '/customer-services/orders/create?orderNumber',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/customerServices/orders/save.html',
    controller: 'SaveOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    params: {
        accountNumber: null,
    },
    resolve: {

        // If we have an order number, we populate the new order
        order: ['$q', '$stateParams', 'OrderService', 'SaveOrderService', function ($q, $stateParams, service, shared) {

            // Get our order number
            var orderNumber = $stateParams.orderNumber;

            // Defer our promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // If we have an order number
            if (orderNumber) {

                // Get our order from the system
                service.get(orderNumber).then(function (response) {

                    // Loop through the current lines
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.lines.length; i++) {

                        // Get the current line
                        var line = response.lines[i];

                        // Set to disabled
                        line.disabled = true;
                    }

                    // Assign our models
                    shared.order = response;

                    // Resolve our promise
                    deferred.resolve();
                });

            // If we don't have an order number
            } else {

                // Resolve our promise anyway
                deferred.resolve();
            }

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }],

        // Updates the account number in our order
        updateAccount: ['$stateParams', 'SaveOrderService', function ($stateParams, shared) {

            // Assigns the account number to the parameter if it has been passed
            shared.order.accountNumber = $stateParams.accountNumber;
        }]
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Add order'
    }
}).state('createOrder.lines', {
    url: '/lines',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/customerServices/orders/save/lines.html',
            controller: 'SaveOrderLinesController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    params: {
        id: null
    },
    resolve: {
        validate: ['$state', '$stateParams', '$timeout', 'SaveOrderService', function ($state, $stateParams, $timeout, shared) {

            console.log(shared);

            // If we don't have an account number
            if (!shared.order.accountNumber) {

                // Timeout to avoid digest issues
                $timeout(function () {

                    // Redirect to the create order view
                    $state.go('createOrder', { orderNumber: $stateParams.orderNumber });
                });
            }
        }],

        // Genearates a default order line for selects an existing one for editing
        orderLine: ['$stateParams', 'ArrayService', 'SaveOrderService', function ($stateParams, arrayService, shared) {

            // Get our id
            var id = $stateParams.id;

            // If we have an id
            if (id) {

                // Get our index
                var index = arrayService.indexOf(shared.order.lines, { id: id }, 'id');

                // If our index is greater than -1
                if (index > -1) {

                    // Return the current line
                    return shared.order.lines[index];
                }
            }

            // Falback, return blank (ish) order line
            return {
                forDelivery: true,
                quantity: 1,
                unitOfMeasure: 0
            };
        }],

        // If we have an existing line, gets the product
        product: ['ProductService', 'SaveOrderService', 'orderLine', function (service, shared, orderLine) {

            // If we have a product
            if (orderLine.productCode) {

                // Return our product
                return service.get(orderLine.productCode, shared.order.accountNumber);
            }

            // Fallback, return nothing
            return null;
        }]
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Add order : Lines'
    }
})
```

What I would like is for my "**order**" resolve to resolve before any resolves are called on the child state (**createOrder.lines**). I thought using a promise would do this, but my validation keeps failing if I go straight to the lines view when supplying an **orderNumber**.

Does anyone know how I can get the order to resolve before the validation on the lines state?

Comment: I don't see where your child state code is waiting for the promise in the parent to resolve. Shouldn't you have a $q.all() or something waiting until all the dependencies of the child validation code are ready?

Comment: because the orderNumber is optional, I have to create a promise. So (in theory) the promise is what is returned and the view will not be shown until the promise has either rejected or resolved. In my case, if we have an order number, the promise will not be resolved until the service promise has resolved. If there is no order number, the promise will resolve straight away. I don't need a $q.all() because I am not chaining.

Comment: Yes I didn't quite get it on first skim, the docs seem to be clear on this though. Although honestly I'm still getting my head around exactly how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found in the ui-router docs for inherited resolved dependencies...

> The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to
>   wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the
>   children.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies

Comment: I thought this might be the case, shame really because I don't need do anything with the resolve in the child state.